# Include plain java projects as dependency at gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jhipster

I have two projects
one plain java project and one gradle spring project created from jhipster

I would like to use the java project alongside with the gradle one.
After search on the net i have found how to do it [link1](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/) but this works only if all my projects are gradles.
Also when i try to add module dependency from Project Structure does not work.

Project tree

```
workspace
-project1
--build.gradle
-project2
```

What is the right way of doin this?

Also why i cannot make changes from IDE's project structure and automatically update build.gradle and settings.gradle with the new dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Change the plain java project into a gradle project, change the two projects into a gradle multi-project.

It's not hard to do, the plain java project probably just needs an almost empty build.gradle file and the settings.gradle file just needs to include it.

An IDE cannot help you much in these tasks, you will have to do most of it manually.

Comment: How would you specify dependencies in a "plain" Java project?

Comment: In the plain java project's build.gradle you need to add only the dependencies of the plain java project (maybe none).